# SQL 2000 trouble returing well formed XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am having trouble returning the following query in well formed XML. The best I can figure is to use the AUTO, Elements but that doesn't return any root. Any help is appreciated. I have no issues in SQL 2005 or above, just trouble with SQL 2000 (which will be getting upgraded soon :) )

```
SELECT 
 dbid AS DatabaseID
,NAME AS DatabaseName
,CASE 
    WHEN NAME IN ('master','mb','model','tempdb','distribution') THEN 'S'
    ELSE 'U'
 END AS SysUserType 
,cmptlevel AS CompatibilityLevel
,databasepropertyex(NAME, 'Collation') AS CollationName
,CASE databasepropertyex(NAME, 'Status') 
    WHEN 'ONLINE'              THEN 0
    WHEN 'RESTORING'           THEN 1
    WHEN 'RECOVERING'          THEN 2
    WHEN 'RECOVERY_PENDING'    THEN 3
    WHEN 'SUSPECT'             THEN 4
    WHEN 'EMERGENCY'           THEN 5
    WHEN 'OFFLINE'             THEN 6
    WHEN 'COPYING'             THEN 7
 END AS State
,databasepropertyex(NAME, 'Status') AS StateDesc
,CASE databasepropertyex(NAME, 'Recovery')
    WHEN 'FULL'                THEN 1
    WHEN 'BULK_LOGGED'         THEN 2
    WHEN 'SIMPLE'              THEN 3
 END AS RecoveryModel
,databasepropertyex(NAME, 'Recovery') AS RecoveryModelDesc
,crdate AS DatabaseCreationDate
,(SELECT MAX(bs.backup_finish_date) FROM msdb.dbo.backupset AS bs WHERE bs.database_name=name) AS LastBackupDate  
,(SELECT (SUM(saf.size) * 8 / 1024) FROM sysaltfiles AS saf WHERE saf.dbid=dbid) AS  SizeMB
,(SELECT COUNT(sp.dbid) FROM sysprocesses AS sp WHERE dbid > 0 AND spid >= 51 AND sp.dbid=dbid) AS ActiveDBConnections 
,SERVERPROPERTY('Machinename') AS SQLServerName
,CASE 
    WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('Instancename') IS NULL
        THEN 'Default'
    ELSE SERVERPROPERTY('Instancename')
    END AS SQLServerInstanceName
,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS SQLServerVersion
,SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS SQLServerEdition
FROM sysdatabases  
ORDER BY DatabaseID
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

Comment: Wait for the upgrade to supported software.

Comment: If you're running the query from .NET, you might consider just running a "normal" query, then converting the dataset to XML

Answer (score 0):

As SQL-Server 2000 does not know *real XML data type* and returns just a string, you might go the easy way:

```
SELECT N'<root>' + (Your FOR XML AUTO,ELEMENTS query here) + N'</root>';
```

But I do not have a 2000 Server for testing...

Good luck!